# How to make a sub-list with numbers (at LyX)

Tags: lyx, lists, enumerate

How do I make a sub-list with numbers? i.e.:

```
1.  
2. 
  2.1
  2.2
3.
```

instead of:

```
1.  
2. 
  a.
  b.
3.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label =\theenumi.\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text \\
OR

\item Text
\end{enumerate}
\item Some other Text
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\roman*)]
\item Text
\item Text
\end{enumerate}

OR
\item Text
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I'm using Hebrew, so how change direction?  

Because I get  under 2, for example, 1.2, 2.2, 3.3...     
How do I fix this?

Comment: Oh! That will be a little different, I suppose. I can't test, but try `\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label =`\arabic*.\theenumi}`.

Comment: @Yoav Fridman: I've just seen there are `e-TeX`primitives` that allos for a left-to-right typesetting inside  a group, `\beginL` and `\endL`. So you also might try: `\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label =\beginL\theenumi.\arabic*\endL}`.

Comment: What is the meaning of '\theenumi'? it's all the "series" until the first lever right?  So '\theenumv'? it's all the "series" until the 5 level, right? Thank you!!

Comment: `\theenumi` is the command to  display the counter of the first level of an enumeration. So the optional argument I gave says to first print the first level counter (in whatever form it is – here, the default arabic), then a dot, then the second level counter in its arabic form.